# Like structure table with Laravel and showing the most popular content at top

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I am using Laravel to creating a website, my users can post questions and other users can write their comments under the post, each comment have Up vote and Down vote, and users can voting for comments.

I need most liked (Up vote) shows topper than others..

This is my database structure and I join them together:

**comment table:**

```
comment_id  |  question_id  |  user_id  |  timestamp
```

**up and down votes table (like):**

```
like_id    |   comment_id   | like_type | user_id  | timestamp
```

*note:**like_type** is an enum on mysql and its values are **upvote** and **downvote**.*

**1-What is the mysql query and Laravel codes for that?**

**2-Is my database Structure right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Calculate `SUM` belongs to Each Comment

2.Make it order by Desc

```
select * from (
select ct.comment_id,ct.question_id,
ct.user_id,SUM(case when vt.like_type='upvote' then 1 else -1 end )
cnt from commenttable ct 
from votestable 
vt left join
on
vt.comment_id=ct.comment_id
)D order by D.cnt desc
```

Comment: Really Really Thanks, Really. Is not this slow?

Comment: you can check and let me know it will not be slow

Comment: What is `ct` and `cnt` and `vt`? is there any article to read and learn SQL more?

Comment: @LASH `ct` and `vt` are aliases names for table just for referencing  columns from different tables and `cnt` contains sum of upvote and down vote